# не загружается изображение в canvas

Tags: javascript, html, html5, canvas

```js
function Up () {
    var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d'),
    img = new Image(),
 img.src = "ava1.png",
    img.src = src;
    img.onload = function() {
   context.drawlmage(img, 0, 0, 480, 402);
    }
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="Up()" >add logo</button>
<canvas id="canvas" width="480" height="402"></canvas>
```

при нажатии на кнопку ничего не происходит.
почему так?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что куча ошибок:

- вместо `img.src = "ava1.png",` должно быть `src = "ava1.png";` причем в конце должна быть точка с запятой
- вместо `context......` должно быть `ctx.....`
- вместо `drawlmage` должно быть `drawImage`

```js
function Up () {
    var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d'),
    img = new Image(),
    src = "http://s00.yaplakal.com/pics/pics_original/3/2/0/6784023.jpg";
    img.src = src;
    img.onload = function() {
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 480, 402);
    }
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="Up()" >add logo</button>
<canvas id="canvas" width="480" height="402"></canvas>
```

Comment: можете пожалуйста глянуть этот вопрос? http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/595844/js-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82-canvas-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%8E-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%8F%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B0