# JS элемент canvas не полностью сохраняется как картинка

Tags: javascript, html, html5, canvas

сначала с компьютера загружается основное изображение, а затем логотип на прозрачном фоне. после чего нужно скачать картинку с наложенным логотипом

итоговая картинка сохраняется нормально, если оба изображения загружены через меню Choose file. Но если основное изображение загружено через Choose file, а логотип - кнопкой Add logo. То он виден в canvas, но итоговая картинка сохраняется без него, как буд-то логотип не добавлен.

п.с. если не нажимать кнопку Add logo всё работает в консоле на этом сайте.
вот пример логотипа http://chu93.aphp.fr/wp-content/blogs.dir/32/files/2015/10/LOGO-YOUTUBE.png

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'),
  ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

function draw() { //загрузка картинки из файла
  var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d'),
    img = new Image(),
    f = document.getElementById("uploadimage").files[0],
    url = window.zURL || window.webkitURL,
    src = url.createObjectURL(f);
  img.src = src;
  img.onload = function() {
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 480, 400);
  }
}
document.getElementById("uploadimage").addEventListener("change", draw, false)

function Up() { //загрузка логотипа
  var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d'),
    img = new Image(),
    src = "http://chu93.aphp.fr/wp-content/blogs.dir/32/files/2015/10/LOGO-YOUTUBE.png";
  img.src = src;
  img.onload = function() {
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 480, 400);
  }
}

function doCanvas() { //отрисовка пустого поля
  ctx.fillStyle = '#f90';
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.fillStyle = '#fff';
  ctx.font = '60px sans-serif';
  ctx.fillText('Pls choose img', 7, canvas.height / 2 - 10);
}

function download() { //скачиване картинки
  var dt = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');
  this.href = dt;
};
downloadLnk.addEventListener('click', download, false);
```

```html
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1251">
</head>

<body onload="doCanvas()">
  <input type='file' name='img' size='0' id='uploadimage' />
  <button type="button" onclick="Up()">Add logo</button>
  <a id="downloadLnk" download="img.jpg">Download</a>
  <button onclick="doCanvas()">Clear</button>
  </br>
  <canvas id="canvas" width="480" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="config.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var img = new Image;
img.src = ctx.toDataURL;

document.getElementById(ид_кнопки).addEventListener('click', function() {
   ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, canvas_width, canvas_height)
});
```

Сохраняем canvas-рисунок в переменной img, дальше при нажатии на кнопку рисуем этот рисунок. `canvas_width` и `canvas_height` - ширина и высота canvas соответственно.

Твоя ошибка была в том, что ты забыл объявить переменную типа Image(), то есть не `var dt = file.png` (твой, неправильный вариант), а `var dt = new Image(); dt.src = file.png;` (правильный вариант).